# Not able to update anything in my wordpress site which I backuped in Localhost XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to activate any plugin in my wordpress site in localhost (XAMPP) which I cloned from my live site. And same error I am getting when I am trying to change setting/reading options.

**Access Forbidden!**

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. Error 403

Any Help plz....

Comment: maybe permissions on plugin folders, ie folder cant be read by web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your htaccess. Add this to you httpd.conf

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Happy coding!